# Packing bounds for sumsets, or, very discrete balls

Tags: discrete-geometry, additive-combinatorics, sphere-packing

Let $D\subset \mathbb{F}_2^n$ with $D=-D$ and $0\in D$. Write $k D$ for the set of all sums of $k$ (not necessarily distinct) elements of $D$. (This is the "ball" in the title.)

Now let $d(g,h)$ be the normalized Hamming distance, i.e., the number of entries of $g-h\in \mathbb{F}_2^n$ that are equal to $0$, divided by $n$. (For instance, for $e_1=(1,0,...,0)$, we have $d(e_1,0) = 1/n$.)

Suppose that $d(g,0)>1/3$ for every element $g$ of $100 D$ distinct from $0$. 
What upper bound can be give on the number of elements of $D$?

(Note: if we assumed $d(g,0)>\delta$ just for every element $g$ of $2D$ ($=D-D$) distinct from $0$, we would have a very good (i.e., tiny) upper bound on the number of elements of $D$ for $\delta>1/2$,
and a much larger upper bound (exponential on $n$) for $\delta<1/2$. I'm looking for tiny bounds.)

Comment: $D=-D$ automatically in $\mathbb F_2^n$.

Comment: Heehee. Sure. Answer it in $\mathbb{F}_3^n$ if you prefer.

Comment: Are you thinking of relations to error-correcting codes? I think as $k\to\infty$ the question reduces to the rate of a linear code with minimum distance $n/3$, whereas with $k=1$ you want the rate of an arbitrary (i.e. nonlinear) code containing zero whose other words all have weight at least $n/3$. The latter should be at least the rate of an arbitrary code with minimum distance $n/3$ which should be constant, i.e. $D=kD$ is exponential-size in $n$. And for fixed $k=100$ with $n\to\infty$ one might heuristically expect the latter behavior. (Hope a codes expert can check and correct me here).

Comment: Excuse my ignorance - is the rate for a linear code with minimum distance $n/3$ bounded from below by a positive constant?

Comment: I think that should be right especially nonconstructively, would feel more comfortable if an expert would confirm.

Answer (score 3):

I think for $100D$ you can still only expect an exponential bound for $\delta=1/3$ (or any $\delta<1/2$).  Let $d=(d_1, \dots, d_k)$, where the $d_i$ are uniform and independent on $\mathbb{F}_2^n$ (it may be the case that some $d_i$ are equal, but the probability of this occurring is negligible if $k<2^{n/2}$, and even for larger $k$ there are likely to only be a small number of repeats).

For any particular $(i_1, \dots, i_{100})$ the sum $d_{i_1}+\dots+d_{i_{100}}$ is also uniform on $\mathbb{F}_2^n$.  In particular, we the probability its distance from $0$ is at most $1/3$ is at most $2^{-cn}$ for some constant $c>0$.

There are less than $k^{100}$ sums in $100D$, and each is close to $0$ with probability at most $2^{-cn}$, so the probability $100D$ contains an element close to $0$ is at most $2^{-cn}k^{100}$.  If $k$ is a sufficiently slowly growing exponential in $n$, then this is less than $1$, and a random set of size $k$ probably has your property.